# Need an Image Manipulation Program

Tags: print-design, software-recommendation, tools

I need an image manipulation software with certain features, the cost doesn't matter to me.

I am looking for the following features:

A program which enables me to: Make logos and other vector works and allows a little bit of raster aka bitmap editing too. I need images to be able to be optimized for print and on-screen media (i.e smartphones and laptops). I would like some kind of Batch Processing and the program should be easy and have a lesser learning curve.

I don't need a complete suite, I just need one program that does these things.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your requirements are extremely broad and, at times, opposing.  Please see [this meta answer](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/279/690) for more info.

Comment: I think it's a fair enough question to ask. A good answer would explain why you probably need at least two applications, and the extent to which CS apps are integrated or overlap.

Answer (score 3):

[Adobe Fireworks](http://www.adobe.com/products/fireworks.html) will give you a nice mix of vector and bitmap editing. There are plenty of tutorials out there and its interface is pretty standard, so learning it shouldn't be too much of a problem.

Edit: Lots of info given to me about Fireworks on a question I asked and that question [is available here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/989/fireworks-for-website-design-why).

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for this [Adobe Illustrator](http://www.adobe.com/products/illustrator.html)

edit:

Description from adobe

> Adobe® Illustrator® CS5 software helps you create distinctive vector
>   artwork for any project. Take advantage of the precision and power of
>   sophisticated drawing tools, expressive natural brushes, and a host of
>   time-savers.