# Adobe Fireworks Alternative?

Tags: software-recommendation, adobe-fireworks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Need an Image Manipulation Program](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4716/need-an-image-manipulation-program)

I am looking for a good alternative of adobe fireworks for windows. I want Raster+Vector editing tools. Which server the logo design, screenshot modifications and optimizing images for print and web. Thanks for giving me your precious time.

Answer (score 5):

```
"I want Raster+Vector"
```

The primary alternative would be to use a raster illustration program and a vector illustration program. Common in the industry would be Photoshop + Illustrator. For open source, maybe The Gimp + Inkscape.

Alas, Fireworks doesn't really have any direct competition. It is/was a tool designed specifically for on-screen graphics with an equal set of raster and vector tools that, IMHO, were built much more intuitively than the bolted-on vector tools in PhotoShop. I've always preferred Fireworks for web work (though, sadly, most firms have never even tried it and stuck with PhotoShop).

Some products that *may* offer a similar feature would include [Microsoft's line of Expression products](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store?SiteID=msstore&Action=list&categoryID=38336300&keywords=expression&WT.mc_id=pointitsem_US_Expression_generic&wt.term=microsoft%20expression%20%20&wt.campaign=%24%2a%205%20-%20Expression%20%28NEEDS%20new%20Marin%20KW%20tracking%29&wt.content=UMrvA42d&wt.source=google&wt.medium=cpc&WT.srch=1) or perhaps one of [Corel's offerings](http://www.corel.com/).

However, I have heard of very few design firms using either of those products (not that that makes them a poor option, just that they aren't terribly popular).

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing cost is your main issue? If you are looking for a best quality product that does what Fireworks does I don't think you'll find one (I love Fireworks, I just wish Adobe did as much as me).

This site gives pretty well all the alternatives though...

http://alternativeto.net/software/adobe-fireworks/

I hear XaraXtreme is decent but I can't speak for it myself.