# Need A Image Manipulation Program

Tags: print-design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Need an Image Manipulation Program](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4716/need-an-image-manipulation-program)

i need a Image Manipulation Software. I am looking for following features. Cost doesn't matter to me.

Which enables me to-
 Make logo and other vectors works.
 Little bit of raster aka bitmap editing too.
 Need images to be optimized for print and on screen media(Smartphone and Laptops)
 Some kind of Batch Processing.
 Easy and lesser learning Curve.

I can afford the cost. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is off topic for this site since it is not strictly "photography" or "photo processing", it is more like "design" in general. If cost is no issue, you should look at Adobe Creative Suite Master Collection. It is the obvious choice when it comes to raster, vector and designing stuffs?

Comment: You will probably have more luck over at the Graphic Design Stack Exchange, BigGenius

Comment: You want software that does everything and is super easy to learn? Well, that's not going to happen. But in terms of your functional requirements, you want the Adobe Creative Suite.

Comment: Not a possible duplicate, this is an exact duplicate. Voted to close.

Comment: (the only reason it isn't identical verbatim is because I edited the other one for grammar and such.)

Answer (score 0):

Definitely an Adobe Creative Suite solution. You'd want

InDesign - Printing/layout
Illustrator - Logo work and vector drawing
Photoshop - Image manipulation

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your new to the field and need something to learn fast.  Look into `Adobe Fireworks`. It will let you create vector and bitmap images and help you set up web apps as well.  The up side is it is adobe and you can transfer your knowledge to `illustrator` (for vector) and `Photoshop` (for bitmap) at a latter date.  Then move on to learn `InDesign` (for print layout).  If going into web development is a future goal, my best advice would be to learn the code not a WYSIWYG.